# Using Pluck/Without on RethinkDB eqJoin()

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb

I am selecting multiple documents from an array of keys using (as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347960/rql-get-multple-documents-from-list-of-keys-rethinkdb-in-javascript/20349309#20349309)):

```
r.expr([person-id1, person-id2, person-id3])
 .eqJoin(function(doc) { return doc; }, r.table("person"))
 .zip()
```

Then joining to a second table by

```
r.expr([person-id1, person-id2, person-id3])
 .eqJoin(function(doc) { return doc; }, r.table("person"))
 .zip()
 .eqJoin("company_id", r.table("employers"))
 .zip()
```

Which all works great. The only change I'd like to make to optimize the query, is that I only need the `employer_name` from the employers table, as there is a considerable size of data that is otherwise associated with an "employers" document. Because this query only consists of `eqJoins()`, and no "base" table, is there a way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pluck` can actually be chained to any stream. I'd do this like so:

```
r.expr([person-id1, person-id2, person-id3])
 .eqJoin(function(doc) { return doc; }, r.table("person"))
 .zip()
 .eqJoin("company_id", r.table("employers"))
 .pluck({"right" : "employer_name"}, "left")
 .zip()
```

That gives you all of the `"left"` value and only `"employer_name"` from the right value.

Comment: There seems to be a typo in the arguments to `pluck`